# Magento Category Controller not overriding

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, overrides, controllers

I want to create Ajax layerd  navigation...
So for that I want to override category controller..
But I try a lots. but i don't know why this not overriding....

### my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Deepak_Ajaxdeep>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Deepak_Ajaxdeep>
</modules>

<frontend>
   <routers>
            <ajaxdeep>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Deepak_Ajaxdeep</module>
                    <frontName>ajaxdeep</frontName>
                </args>
            </ajaxdeep>
            <catalog>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Deepak_Ajaxdeep before="Mage_Catalog">Deepak_Ajaxdeep_Catalog</Deepak_Ajaxdeep>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalog>
            <catalogsearch>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Deepak_Ajaxdeep before="Mage_CatalogSearch">Deepak_Ajaxdeep_CatalogSearch</Deepak_Ajaxdeep>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalogsearch>
        </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

### controllers

```
require_once('app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php');
class Deepak_Ajaxdeep_Catalog_CategoryController extends Mage_Catalog_CategoryController
{

    public function viewAction()
    {
        echo 'test';exit;
        if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() && (!$this->getRequest()->getParam("fullpageajax") || $this->getRequest()->getParam("ajaxcatalog"))){ //Check if it was an AJAX request
            $response = array();

            if ($category = $this->_initCatagory()) {
                $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
                $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($category);

                // apply custom design
                if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                    $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setLastViewedCategoryId($category->getId());

                $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
                $update->addHandle('default');

                if (!$category->hasChildren()) {
                    $update->addHandle('catalog_category_layered_nochildren');
                }

                $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
                $update->addHandle($category->getLayoutUpdateHandle());
                $update->addHandle('CATEGORY_' . $category->getId());
                $this->loadLayoutUpdates();

                // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
                if ($layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates()) {
                    if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                        foreach($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                            $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                        }
                    }
                }

            $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks(); //Generate new blocks
            $viewpanel = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml();
            $productlist = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list')->toHtml(); // Generate product list
            $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
            $response['viewpanel']=$viewpanel;
            $response['productlist'] = $productlist;

            // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
            }elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
                $response['status'] = 'FAILURE';
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
            return;
        }

        if ($category = $this->_initCatagory()) {
            $design = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/design');
            $settings = $design->getDesignSettings($category);

            // apply custom design
            if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                $design->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setLastViewedCategoryId($category->getId());

            $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
            $update->addHandle('default');

            if (!$category->hasChildren()) {
                $update->addHandle('catalog_category_layered_nochildren');
            }

            $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
            $update->addHandle($category->getLayoutUpdateHandle());
            $update->addHandle('CATEGORY_' . $category->getId());
            $this->loadLayoutUpdates();

            // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
            if ($layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates()) {
                if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                    foreach($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                        $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
            // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
            if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
                $this->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')->applyTemplate($settings->getPageLayout());
            }

            if ($root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')) {
                $root->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $category->getUrlPath())
                ->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getUrlKey());
            }

            $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
            $this->renderLayout();
        }elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }

}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some change require in your code:

No1: **Mage_Catalog** module **CategoryController** properly `not included`.

You need to include this file at your override controller in magento way.

```
require_once('app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php');
```

**Is should be**

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'CategoryController.php';
```

Also you need to create module config file **Deepak_Ajaxdeep.xml at app/etc/modules**